# Update warnings

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

1) Can I automatically receive an email from my Drupal website when new updates are available ?

2) Can Drupal automatically update itself ? Is this risky ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set up a cron job that uses [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) to update Drupal, but any Update can break the website, it is risky to not test them beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

> How to keep up to date on security
>   announcements It is strongly
>   recommended that you always keep your
>   Drupal site up to date with the very
>   latest minor release available, to
>   remove known security vulnerabilities
>   and existing bugs. Here are some of
>   the most common ways to stay informed:
>
> Via your website: One of Drupal's core
>   features is that it is able to check
>   if you are running the very latest
>   release of Drupal, and any installed
>   modules and themes. Drupal.org is also
>   able to send you an email as soon
>   there is a new release out. To check
>   if your installation is up to date:
>   Drupal 7: First enable the core module
>   Update manager (if you have previously
>   disabled it), then go to Administer >
>   Reports > Available updates Drupal 5
>   and 6: First enable the core module
>   Update status (if you have previously
>   disabled it), then go to Administer >
>   Reports > Available updates For more
>   details visit the Update manager
>   module page.
>
> By receiving Security Announcement
>   emails from Drupal.org: You can find
>   the "Security Announcements" box in
>   the Edit > My Newsletters tab of your
>   Drupal.org user account. Via the
>   Security advisories page: You can also
>   subscribe to the page's RSS feed.

from http://drupal.org/upgrade